# DB2, SQL query to SUM 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add to columns in a row.
Table Data

| id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 11 | 20 |
| 3 | 12 | 20 |

Result expected

| id | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 32 |

I tried `sum(col1 + col2)`, but that gives the sum of all the columns together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum()` is a *aggregating* function (one that give a single result for a group of rows), not a *algebraic* one: You want the *addition* (the *mathematical* sum) of the two columns:

```
select id, col1 + col2 as sum
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

we have two type of columns in group clause (Aggregation column and Group column) in this query

```
select id, col1 + col2 as sum
from mytable 
group by id
```

we have to insert `id`, `col1` and `col2` in front of `group by`, otherwise we get this error

> Column 'TEST.COL1' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

if use `MAX()` aggregation function like this

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(COL1+COL2) AS SUM
FROM TEST
GROUP BY ID
```

we get the result BUT this isn't good idea because the cost of this code 4 times more than
bellow code

```
SELECT
    ID,COL1+COL2 AS SUM
FROM TEST
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select id, col1 + col2 as sum
from mytable 
group by id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: you can ask the question and i'll try to answer that like show your table and expected result